# How to make a List of ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx

I am going to use several similar comboBoxes for my javafx project so i thought it would be much simpler to add them to a List() and controll them from there, but im having problems with it because its not sharing the reference and cant access the itens inside it.

i can add the combobox to the List but i gives error when i try to access its itens, even when i add it to the List before and after setting the items;

...

```
public class Controller {
  @FXML
  public ComboBox<String> box1 = new ComboBox<>();
  public List<ComboBox<String>> boxes = new List<ComboBox<String>>(){};

  public void initialize(){
      boxes.add(box1);
      box1.getItems().setAll("a","b","c");
      /*The line below gives NullPointer Exception even when i add the items to the combobox and then add it to the List*/
      System.out.println(boxes.get(0).getItems());

  }

  public void boxOnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
      System.out.println(boxes.get(0).getValue());
  }

}
```

...

I would like to know if theres any chance that it can work so that if i change the values of the comboboxes it also changes the value of the one inside the List and also make it possible to get the value of the combobox by calling it from the List.

Comment: You do not seem to using `java.util.List`: `java.util.List` is an interface with unimplemented methods; therefore using `new List<ComboBox<String>>(){}` to create one would result in a compile time error because of the missing implementations... Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hint: `new List<ComboBox<String>>(){};` those { } ... do **not** do that. You have to understand each and any character that you put into your code. Do you understand what effect these brackets have there? No, so, why did you put them there?! (they create an instance of an anonymous inner class ... which actually does not implement the list interface, so you are probably facing a compiler error). But as explained: if you ask about broken code, include your error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your **List** as an Implementation of **List**. **List** is only an interface.

Also make sure you are using the right imports for the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Your could use ArrayList<>(); for example:

```
 public List<ComboBox<String>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was using new List<>(), i changed it to new ArrayList<>() and worked.

Comment: No problem :) This is happening to every one at some point :D